# How do I change directory back to my original working directory with Python?

Tags: python

I have a function that resembles the one below. I'm not sure how to use the os module to get back to my original working directory at the conclusion of the jar's execution.

```
def run(): 
    owd = os.getcwd()
    #first change dir to build_dir path
    os.chdir(testDir)
    #run jar from test directory
    os.system(cmd)
    #change dir back to original working directory (owd)
```

note: I think my code formatting is off - not sure why. My apologies in advance

Comment: If you put four spaces before each line of your code, SO will format it more nicely.

Comment: I just fixed that for @Amara :) .. they had used a <pre> tag to open, but a </code> to end. It's all clean and happy now, though :D

Comment: Also answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299249/how-can-i-get-my-python-version-25-script-to-run-a-jar-file-inside-a-folder-ins.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to use the os module to get back to my original working directory at the conclusion of the jar's execution. " I don't understand how there is a question. OP clearly knew how to find out the original working directory, and how to set the current working directory to a given path. So - use the "set current working directory" thingy, and tell it to use "the original working directory" (already saved in a variable) as the directory to set it to? *What exactly is the difficulty*?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You simply need to add the line:

```
os.chdir(owd)
```

Just a note this was also answered in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299249/how-can-i-get-my-python-version-25-script-to-run-a-jar-file-inside-a-folder-ins).

Comment: Noted. :) I Wanted to ensure my question was more specific and detailed in order to get the best help and also, post a code sample to add some more clarity to my question.

Answer (score 79):

A context manager is a very appropriate tool for this job:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

@contextmanager
def cwd(path):
    oldpwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(oldpwd)
```

...used as:

```
os.chdir('/tmp') # for testing purposes, be in a known directory
print(f'before context manager: {os.getcwd()}')
with cwd('/'):
    # code inside this block, and only inside this block, is in the new directory
    print(f'inside context manager: {os.getcwd()}')

print(f'after context manager: {os.getcwd()}')
```

...which will yield something like:

```
before context manager: /tmp
inside context manager: /
after context manager: /tmp
```

This is actually **superior** to the `cd -` shell builtin, inasmuch as it also takes care of changing directories back when a block is exited due to an exception being thrown.

---

For your specific use case, this would instead be:

```
with cwd(testDir):
    os.system(cmd)
```

---

Another option to consider is using `subprocess.call()` instead of `os.system()`, which will let you specify a working directory for the command to run:

```
# note: better to modify this to not need shell=True if possible
subprocess.call(cmd, cwd=testDir, shell=True)
```

... which would prevent you from needing to change the interpreter's directory at all.

Note that now it is recommended to use `subprocess.run` (instead of `call`) but the same arguments are available, and in particular `cwd`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module.

Comment: Thanks for the .call(cwd=...) idea!

Comment: @Jean-Francois Please be a bit more light-handed in making edits that don't improve correctness (or PEP-8 compliance, which the spacing fix f/e certainly does). Some of the changes from single to double quotes are ones I don't particularly agree with from a personal stylistic choice perspective, and I'm unaware of any correctness or convention reason for the change at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry for that. I'm biased by my extensive usage of `black`, which uses `"` as a default for string. And it's true that PEP-8 (or Google-Style for what matters) doesn't recommend one over the other. I reverted the quotes.

Answer (score 17):

The advice to use `os.chdir(owd)` is good.  It would be wise to put the code which needs the changed directory in a `try:finally` block (or in python 2.6 and later, a `with:` block.)  That reduces the risk that you will accidentally put a `return` in the code before the change back to the original directory.

```
def run(): 
    owd = os.getcwd()
    try:
        #first change dir to build_dir path
        os.chdir(testDir)
        #run jar from test directory
        os.system(cmd)
    finally:
        #change dir back to original working directory (owd)
        os.chdir(owd)
```

Comment: Ah perfect i was looking for a way to guarantee a return the original dir, thought I would need to use a with clause but this works too

Answer (score 10):

#### Python 3.11 update:

You can now simply use [`contextlib.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.chdir) from stdlib. It changes the directory when entering the block, it then restores the old directory back:

```py
from contextlib import chdir
from os import getcwd

print(f"Before: {getcwd()}")

with chdir("/"):
    print(f"inside: {getcwd()}")

print(f"after: {getcwd()}")
```

Answer (score 3):

A context-manager is overkill for this situation (executing a system command). The best solution is to use the `subprocess` module instead (Python 2.4 onwards) and the `run` or `popen` methods with the `cwd` argument.

So, your code can be replaced with:

```py
def run(): 
    #run jar from test directory
    subprocess.run(cmd, cwd=testDir)
```

See https://bugs.python.org/issue25625 and https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements.

Answer (score 2):

os.chdir(owd) should do the trick (like you've done when changing to testDir)

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive so when typing the path make sure it's the same as the directory
you want to set.

```
import os

os.getcwd()

os.chdir('C:\\')
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is Python that is case sensitive, I think it's the operating system that is (Linux, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I looked around the answers on StackOverflow and eventually decided to write my own decorator for this purpose:

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')
    
    
def enter_subdir(subdir: str) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    """During the execution of a function, temporarily enter a subdirectory."""

    def decorator(function: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> T:
            os.makedirs(subdir, exist_ok=True)
            os.chdir(subdir)
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            os.chdir("..")
            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```