# Python equivalent of "cd -"

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I am writing a script that should change directory based on the input and then go back to the directory where the script was executed.

I am currently doing this:

```
old_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(<new_dir>)
#do something
os.chdir(old_dir)
#do something
```

Is there a Python equivalent of `cd -` which would change the directory to the previous directory?

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299446/how-do-i-change-directory-back-to-my-original-working-directory-with-python) expects an answer using any module while what I am looking for is something similar to `cd -`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing already *is* the equivalent of `cd -`.

The `cd` shell builtin updates the `OLDPWD` shell variable (notably "shell variable", not "environment variable", so the value isn't inherited by subprocesses), and that value is used for `cd -`. However, there's no underlying operating system call equivalent to this; it's purely a shell function. As such, in a non-shell language, maintaining a similar variable is your own responsibility if you want to be able to revert.

---

One thing you might consider is a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def cwd(path):
    oldpwd=os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(oldpwd)
```

...used as:

```
os.chdir('/tmp') # for testing purposes, be in a known directory
print 'before context manager: %s' % os.getcwd()
with cwd('/'):
    print 'inside context manager: %s' % os.getcwd()
print 'after context manager: %s' % os.getcwd()
```

...which will yield something like:

```
before context manager: /tmp
inside context manager: /
after context manager: /tmp
```

---

This is actually **superior** to the shell builtin for which you're requesting an equivalent: Unlike `cd -`, this also takes care of changing back when a block is exited due to an exception being thrown, whereas an early function exit triggered by `do_something || return`-style error handling in shell would provide no such guarantee. It also can be nested, and invocations won't overwrite each others `OLDPWD` values -- as would happen if you had nested shell functions using `cd -`.

Comment: Wow! learnt a lot! thank you. I read the following questions before posting this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462833/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-previous-directory-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299446/how-do-i-change-directory-back-to-my-original-working-directory-with-python. But none of the answers are as good as yours. Is there a way to link them to this answer?

Comment: Hmm. I think the answer is also applicable to the latter -- in fact, I might copy it over there and close this question as duplicative of it, or the inverse. For the former it's merely related; a comment with a link might be appropriate.

Comment: Sure, Please do what seems right.

Comment: ...actually, just realized these questions are tagged `python`, whereas my gold-badge dupe-closing powers are limited to `bash`, `shell`, and maybe these days `unix`, so we'll have some other folks weighing in on what seems the appropriate resolution rather than having it be a unilateral decision anyhow. :)