# Using Python method to generate files in a specific directory without changing to this dir using os.chdir?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am executing an imported method in my Python program which generates a bunch of files in the current directory. When I execute it I want to stay in the current directory and instead want it to generate the files in a different directory that I make on the fly, without changing to this directory using `os.chdir`. What I currently have is that I make the dir, then I change to it using `os.chdir` and finally change back to the base dir.

Let's say cwd is `/home/user/project/`,
I create `/home/user/project/uploads/files/` the files directory is created in the uploads dir and the files are subsequently generated here here. Lastly I switch back to the base dir `/home/user/project/`

```
base_dir = os.getcwd()
os.mkdir("/home/user/project/uploads/files/")
os.chdir("/home/user/project/uploads/files/")
method()
os.chdir(base_dir)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `os.mkdir('path/to/destination')`

Comment: @bullseye Sure, but I would then want to generate the files in this directory, _whilst_ staying in the base dir. So the last 3 lines basically is what I am trying to optimize, where method() is the imported function that generates the files in the current directory. Is there a way to do this more efficiently without `os.chdir` to the created dir and then back to `base_dir`?

Comment: What do you mean by generate files? Can you edit the question and provide a full example?

Comment: It sounds like to get the behavior you want, you need to modify your method that creates the files to accept a path, rather than automatically creating files in the current directory

Comment: @bullseye The imported method() function generates a bunch of files with .pdb extension in the working dir. There's nothing wrong with this code per se, since it works. But I was just wondering if there's a shorter way to do it where I don't need to change directories at all and can execute the code and the files will appear in the created files/ directory. Because the imported method() function does not take a path parameter, it just always generates the files in the working dir.

Comment: @jdaz That's what I was thinking of as well, but unfortunately does not accept a path parameter.

Comment: Rewrite `method()` to accept a directory as a parameter ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change directory back to my original working directory with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299446/how-do-i-change-directory-back-to-my-original-working-directory-with-python)